# how to read an sql file into sqlite command in Mac terminal window

Tags: database, macos, sqlite

I am trying to point to a file I have under a path. 
my `test2.sql` look like this:

```
create table setting (id integer primary key, status text)
insert into setting values (1, 'new')
```

When I type this command:

```
sqlite> .read users/name/test2.sql
```

I get this error:

```
Error: cannot open "test2.sql"
```

or behaves as if it has executed without error but no records get added to the table.

I do

```
sqlite> select * from setting;
```

and that goes back to:

```
sqlite>
```

Are there any gotchas to using the `.read` command?

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path like /Users/name/test2.sql ?

Comment: without .read you mean?

Comment: Sorry, no. The full command would be:
`.read /Users/name/test2.sql`

Comment: Try `select * from setting;` rather than `select * from question;`

Comment: I tried this too .read /Users/name/test2.sql and it didn't work

Comment: Try adding a semicolon after `create table (...);` and after `insert into (...);`

Comment: I am sorry I meant to say select * from setting;

Comment: Try opening `test2.sql` in a separate window and copying just the first line from it and pasting it into the `sqlite>` prompt. Then the second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, each SQL statement *must* end with a semicolon.

```
-- file: test2.sql
create table setting (id integer primary key, status text);
insert into setting values (1, 'new');
```

Second, when the database and the file "test2.sql" are in the same directory, you can `.read` the file using only the file name. Double quotes around the file name avoids errors when there are spaces in the file name.

```
$ sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.8.7.2 2014-11-18 20:57:56
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .read "test2.sql"

sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode columns
sqlite> select * from setting;
id          status    
----------  ----------
1           new
```

Using the full path should always work. Double quote full paths, too, if there might be spaces in the file name. The string `users/name/test2.sql` isn't a full path. Full paths always start with `/`. (The directory separator in POSIX paths is `/`; in HFS paths the separator is `:`.) You should also be aware that some (most?) filesystems are case-sensitive: `/users/name/test2.sql` and `/Users/name/test2.sql` are two different things.

You can also read the file using command-line redirection. Again, if the database and the SQL file are in the same directory, you can just use the file name.

```
$ rm test.db
$ sqlite3 test.db < "test2.sql"
$ sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.8.7.2 2014-11-18 20:57:56
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode columns
sqlite> select * from setting;
id          status    
----------  ----------
1           new
```

Finally, check permissions on the SQL file.

```
$ ls -l "test2.sql"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mike mike 118 Jan 15 09:28 test2.sql
```

If you don't have read permissions on the file, you won't be able to open it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I just tried it one more time. I created an .sql file that has that table creation and insert statement inside test3.sql in my home directory (name).
I then tried to .read "test2.sql" but quickly get: cannot open test3.sql

Comment: Check file permissions. `ls -l test*.sql` Trying to read a file you don't have read permissions for will return "cannot open filename".

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because sqlite working directory and SQL files are not same even though you put sqlite3.exe file in the same folder with SQL files.

- To check sqlite working directory type .shell pwd on your command line
- Then if you want to change sqlite working directory to SQL files, you can type: .cd full-path_SQL_files
- Next time you don't need to input full path of SQL files into command line anymore

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with using .read to execute my .sql file even though I put .sql file in the same directory as the SQLite executable. Using the full path of .sql file fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with the name of the file if you're working in Windows.  Windows hides extensions by default.  What you see as "FN" may really be "FN.txt"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, found that I had named the file test.sql.sql due to windows hiding file extensions (new computer). I renamed the file to test.sql and it worked.

Comment: The same answer has already added by Jia LI. Please add something new to your answer.

Comment: I disagree, my answer has nothing to do with the directory or full path. My answer has to do with hidden extensions doubling up.